# How to run nodemon in different cwd?

Tags: node.js

How to run nodemon in different cwd?

for example I run `nodemon app.js`, but I want to tell nodemon where to run this file. something like

`nodemon app.js --cwd C:/usr/`

Comment: You could do something like this: `cd ./cwd && nodemon script.js`

Answer (score 1):

so you would first need to go to the directory you want to work from and then you would run nodemon /path/to/app.js